# Symfony2 : how to translate @Assert\Callback message

Tags: symfony, twig, translate

I have a callBack methode in my entitie

```
@Assert\Callback(methods={"isStudentsOK"}) 
....
public function isStudentsOK(ExecutionContext $context)
{
  if ( $this->students->isEmpty())
    $context->addViolationAtSubPath('students', 'Missing students informations', array(), null);
}
```

I want to translate le message in my template.
`{{ form_errors(form.student)|trans }}` doesn't work...
I have this

```
<span class="help-inline">Missing students informations</span>
```

Is it a bug ? How can i do ?

**EDIT**

I found the response myself :

I have installed a BootstrapBundle and `{% block form_errors %}` is displayed inside a span

I have override the `form_div_layout.html.twig` template.

Comment: You should write an answer and mark it as THE answer, instead of leaving this question opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using the |trans filter, so I'm assuming you're using the Twig i18n extension which in turn uses PHP's gettext functions.

If your PHP code generates the message, you might as well do the translation there:

```
@Assert\Callback(methods={"isStudentsOK"}) 
....
public function isStudentsOK(ExecutionContext $context)
{
  if ( $this->students->isEmpty())
    $context->addViolationAtSubPath('students', _('Missing students informations'), array(), null);
}
```

Notice the underscore function at your error message. This is the PHP equivalent of the "Trans" filter.

Answer (score 0):

As `Symfony >= 6.2` ([Blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-better-php-translation-extractor)), you can use [TranslatableMessage](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.4/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/TranslatableMessage.php) class directly.

Your assert should look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatableMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

#[Assert\Callback]
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, mixed $payload): void
{
    if ($this->students->isEmpty()) {
        $context->buildViolation(new TranslatableMessage('myEntity.students.empty', [], 'validators'))
                ->atPath('students')
                ->addViolation()
        ;
    }
}
```

With Symfony command `bin/console translation:extract --force en`,
in `translations/validators.en.xlf`:

```
<trans-unit id="i3PmZjY" resname="myEntity.students.empty">
   <source>myEntity.students.empty</source>
   <target>Missing students informations</target>
</trans-unit>
```